# LaTeX equivalent of &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; in HTML?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

In HTML, to get extra horizontal spacing all I would have to do is:

```html
This is textual phrase A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is textual phrase B
```

to get the following output:

```
This is textual phrase A...This is textual Phrase B
```

. = *1 invisible space character*

**Question#1: How do you force insert space characters?**

**Question#2: What is the proper way to fine control horizontal spacing instead of force adding space characters?**

Comment: *What* do you want to achieve in the "fine control" you ask about in your second question? If you explained that, it might become an answerable question :)

Comment: Fine control as in I can specify by a metric value instead of calculating how many space characters to insert, The \hspace{5em} example from Werner seems to be the best answer.

Comment: You'll find a list of the different kinds of lengths you can specify in LaTeX [here](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-86.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In answer to your first question: There are many ways of adding specific spaces to text. Some examples include forcing an actual "inter word space" to specifying a regular space length to specifying a length based on an object (text or otherwise). In that order you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}%
\begin{document}
This is textual phrase A\ \ \ This is textual phrase B% 3 inter word spaces
\par
This is textual phrase A\hspace{5em}This is textual phrase B% space of length 5em
\par
This is textual phrase A\hphantom{spaces}This is textual phrase B% space equivalent to length of word 'spaces'
\par
This is textual phrase A\hfill{}This is textual phrase B% infinitely stretchable space
\end{document}
```

This is the equivalent output:

[image: Different spaces]

Perhaps some of these methods answer your second question. However, in its general context, the answers are probably too many to list here.

Answer (score 32):

1. In (La)TeX, a 'tie' `~` is the exactly equivelant of `&nbsp;` in HTML, say, no-break space. However, it is often misused in documents.

   See here to know: [When should I use non-breaking space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space)
2. It is a large topic. Generally speaking, it is better to prevent the direct using of most spacing commands in LaTeX documents. Just use semantic commands and define some if necessary. (c.f. [Do semantics matter in LaTeX? If not, why not?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/do-semantics-matter-in-latex-if-not-why-not)) That's to say, one should use `quote`, `itemize`, `verse`, `quotation`, `abstract` instead of many `\`, `~`, `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\;` or `\hspace`'s. Do fine turning when necessary only.

   Example:

   ```
   % Good
   \title{Foo}
   \author{Bar}
   \maketitle
   ```

   Versus

   ```
   % Bad
   \begin{center}
   {\Large Foo}\\
   Bar
   \end{center}
   ```

   Versus

   ```
   % Awful
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Large{Foo}\\
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Bar
   ```

   Possible fine turning:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   % turn the format in preamble
   \usepackage{titling}
   \pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
   \posttitle{\end{center}\vspace{2ex}}

   \title{Foo}
   \author{Bar}

   \begin{document}
   \maketitle
   % ...
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Would be nice to see the results directly